# The dialog is shown first and then sets the scroll

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, scrollbar, jdialog

I'm developing with asp.net and ajax.

I have a problem with jQuery and scroll.

From c# use the following code to display a jQuery dialog after postback

```
                    script += "$(document).ready(function () {";
                script += "$('#dialog').dialog({";
                script +="        autoOpen: true,";
                script += "       show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 2000},";
                script +="        hide: {effect: 'fade', duration: 500},";
                script +="        modal: true,";
                script +="        resizable: false,";
                script +="        open: function(event, ui) {";
                script +="            setTimeout(function(){";
                script +="                $('#dialog').dialog('close');    ";
                script +="            }, 8000);";
                script +="        }";
                script +="    }); ";
                script += "setTimeout(function() {window.location.href = \"http://localhost:7713/xxxx/xxxx.aspx\";}, 9000);";
                script += "});";

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showMessage", script, true);
```

If I have MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = "false" the code performs well. But if I have MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = "true" shows the jquery Dialog FIRST and THEN sets the scroll so that the dialog is in the top of the page.

Any solution?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I have found the solution in the following code:

```
     . ui-dialog {margin: 0 auto; position: fixed;}
```

Another alternative solution is: http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/240/jquery-dialog-position-problem-web-form-postback

This is a very common problem in ASP.NET

Thank you all!

Comment: English title please.

Comment: @JoseImaz Quite alright. It's nothing personal, please see a more in-depth explanation [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but i faced the same issue and this might be usefull for someone else.

(First, you should create a function in your client side and invoke it, instead of instatiating  a string variable with your code. You'll found it easier to maintain.)

So, in order to your dialog won't scroll to the top, just invoke:

```
WebForm_RestoreScrollPosition();
```

before opening the jquery dialog.